# Who is this girl dressed in an elaborate pink outfit?

Tags: yozakura-quartet

Can you tell me who this anime girl is and what anime she hails from? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That would be V Lila F in Yozakura Quartet: hana no uta

> In a town where humans and demons co-exist, it takes more than a normal police force to maintain the peace. Enter the Hiizumi Life Counseling Office, a fantastic foursome of unique teenagers, each gifted with an amazing super power!
>   Read more at http://myanimelist.net/anime/18497/Yozakura_Quartet:_Hana_no_Uta#Mjd5m0HjSkT8qkkb.99

You can tell its Lila because of that flower on her cheek

Comment: The "V" and "F" in her name stands for "Victor" and "Frankenstein" respectively (which is the the name of her ancestor).